# jquery ui dialog with "farbtastic" color picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

How do I fix that picker "div" that it would be on top of jquery ui dialog and outside of it is it possible to do so? what could be the best solution?

here is what I would like to see:
[1 http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/4866/74030613.png](http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/4866/74030613.png)

http://jsfiddle.net/gt4Ry/2/

html:

```
<div id="settingsDialogWindow" title="Settings" style="display:none;">
  <label for="color">Color:</label>
  <input type="text" id="color" name="color" value="#123456" maxlength="7" />
  <div id="picker" style="position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px !important;
  border-radius: 4px !important;
  z-index: 99999999;"></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(function () {
    $("#settingsDialogWindow").dialog({
        modal: true,
        draggable: true,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 300,
        minWidth: 300,
        minHeight: 60,
        resizable: false,
        position: { at: "center middle" }
    });


    $('#picker').farbtastic('#color');

    $("#color").focus(function () {
        $("#picker").show();
    });
    $("#color").focusout(function () {
        $("#picker").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but...what do you want? You want it to be movable, but outside of the dialog?

Comment: I want that color picker would be on top of jquery ui, now it is wisible just a part of it and scrollbar apears.

Comment: ...for me, it's inside the dialog, that's right. (As it should be, if you want it outside, give it an absolute position (or at least a relative one with left:-50px; or something). However there's no scrollbar.

Comment: how to make it outside of dialog? but it must move with dialog too...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to do that...not much of a design person here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this solves your problem!

http://jsfiddle.net/gt4Ry/15/

Html:

```
 <div id="settingsDialogWindow" title="Settings" style="display:none;">
<label for="color">Color:</label>
<input type="text" id="color" name="color" value="#123456" maxlength="7" />
</div>
 <div id="picker" style="position: absolute;
 display:none;
left: 50px;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
background-color: #fff;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px !important;
border-radius: 4px !important;
z-index: 99999999;">
</div>
```

Js:

```
$(function () {
        $("#settingsDialogWindow").dialog({
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 300,
            minWidth: 300,
            minHeight: 60,
            resizable: false,
            position: { at: "center middle" },
            drag: function( event, ui ) {  
              $("#picker").css({top:ui.position.top+115,left:ui.position.left+30});
            }
        });


        $('#picker').farbtastic('#color');

        $("#color").focus(function () {
            $("#picker").show();
        });
        $("#color").focusout(function () {
            $("#picker").hide();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Do you know how to set its position on startup without draging?

Comment: found: var position = $("#settingsDialogWindow").closest('.ui-dialog').offset();$("#picker").css({ top: position.top + 115, left: position.left + 30 });

Comment: Here http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/ is the doc for the dialog. Try with event  "create: function( event, ui ) {}". Inside the branches add the same code as in "drag:". If does not work for you try with event "open".